# Groovy language: how to get difference between two lists of pairs

Tags: list, groovy, syntax, dictionary

I am trying to get a difference of 1 list of pairs from another in Groovy language. Pairs are just (x,y) coordinates and they are unique.
Below is a small example for simplicity. Note that lists can have dozens of pairs.

```
  def l1 = [[x:1, y:1]]
  def l2 = [[x:0, y:0]]
  println l1 - l2
```

will get [], that is an empty list but should be this: [[x:1,y:1]]

**Update:**

```
 for(n in l2) {
   l1 = l1 - n
 }
```

It works, but it's a black magic and is not optimized

Comment: What do you mean by difference?  You want each x,y from l2 subtracted from the same index in l1?  And you "works for me" example there make things just more confusing, because I doubt it does what you want (just keeps l1)

Comment: @cfrick The difference as in mathematics: we subtract l2 set from l1 set.  The result is = everything in l1 but not in l2. Treat (x,y) as one element, that is (x,y) in l1 but not in l2. Here is a good example: http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2010/08/groovy-goodness-subtracting-map-entries.html

Comment: ic.  there is something odd with the [x:0,y:0] pair.  it works with `minus()`, if one of them is not "falsy"

Comment: i guess the lists can have duplicates and they should remain?

Comment: @cfrick No, pairs are unique. But my first code snippet prints []. it should print [[x:1, y:1]]

Comment: if they are unique, then `l1.toSet()-l2.toSet()` works.  also `l1-[[x:1,y:0]]` works.  Only `[x:0,y:0]` does something odd.

Comment: @cfrick thank you so much! with toSet(), it works!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the pairs in `l1` are unique (or rather: it's ok to have unique results), then you can use l1/l2 as sets:

```
l1 = [[x:1, y:1]]
l2 = [[x:0, y:0]]
println l1.toSet()-l2.toSet()
//; [[x:1, y:1]]
```

The problem originally is the `[x:0,y:0]` vs `[x:1,y:1]` part.  The reason is in [`public static <T> Collection<T> minus(Collection<T> self, Collection<?> removeMe)`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L11121).  The n*n branchs is chosen and the `NumberAwareComperator` thinks both maps are equal:

```
def cmp = new org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NumberAwareComparator()
println cmp.compare(l1[0], l2[0])
//; 0 (equal!)
```

Which simply boils down to:

```
assert [x:1, y:1].hashCode() == [x:0, y:0].hashCode()
    // 120^1 + 121^1 == 120^0 + 121^0
```

**Edit** Alternative (if you can get rid of the map)

As this does not look that good of a base for, you might be better off using a save and sound comparable class for your data.  e.g.:

```
@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Pair {
    long x,y
}

def p00 = new Pair(0,0)
def p11 = new Pair(1,1)
def p11o = new Pair(1,1)

assert [p00]-[p11] == [p00]
assert [p11]-[p00] == [p11]
assert [p00].intersect([p11]) == []
assert [p11].intersect([p00]) == []
assert [p11].intersect([p11o]) == [p11]
assert [p11].intersect([p11o]) == [p11o]
```

Even turning the maps into `Expando`s works better.

Comment: btw, [[x:0, y:0]].toSet().intersect([[x:1, y:1]]).toSet() doesn't work either and I don't have a workaround. Most likely I will have to check this 0/0 and deal with it separately.

Comment: And [x:1, y:1].hashCode() == [x:0, y:0].hashCode() makes me think it's a bug in Groovy. They treat them the same, weird.

Comment: @vibneiro this is java code there.  the question is, does NumberAwareComperator shortcut a little to much with using just the hashCodes there.  basically the hashcode is `120^1 + 121^1 == 120^0 + 121^0`.  there are clashes all over the place.